# Countable dense subset of functions of exponential type 1 that decay along the positive real axis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, topological-vector-spaces

I am interested in the space of all holomorphic function of exponential type one, that decay exponentially along the positive real axis. I tried to define it as follows.

Let
$$\|f\|_n = \sup_{z\in\mathbb{C}}  |f(z)| e^{-(1+\frac1n)|z|} + \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}^+} |f(z)| e^{(1-\frac1n)z} $$
and let $\mathcal A$ be the space of all functions, $f$, such that $\|f\|_n$ is finite for every $n$. Since $\|\cdot\|_n$ is a family of seminorms, $\mathcal A$ is a Frechet space.

It is clear by the definition that polynomials are not in $\mathcal A$. I would like to find a subset  of $\mathcal A$ that is countable and dense.

I think that a good candidate is the span of "monomials" of the type $z^k e^{-z}$, but I couldn't prove that this is a dense set. Is it actually? Is there any other?

Comment: If you are about to downvoted this question for being trivially solved by Liouville's theorem or by Phragmén–Lindelöf principle,please read it once more and pay attention to the sets on which the supremum are taken

Comment: Is it clear that if you just took functions of exponential type $1$ (and dropped the second part of your norm), then the polynomials are dense? That doesn't look completely obvious either.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I somehow missed your comment. I think what you are asking is relatively straightforward since we can truncate the Taylor series and use Taylor's theorem to bound the remainder. I haven't actually done that in detail but I played with it a bit until I got convinced. (We need to keep in mind that the Taylor coefficients of functions of exponential type decay as factorials)